# Custom gradle task "with jar"

Tags: java, gradle

I have multiple similar tasks in a gradle build script. Each of this tasks builds a jar. Task looks like this:

```
task fatJarAndServicePackageXXX(type: Jar) {
    baseName = 'adapter-XXX'
    def mainClass = 'Gateway'
    def specialFlags = ['-Xmx1g']
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    def outPackageName = '../build/' + baseName + '-package.tar.gz'
    def filesToBeIncluded = [
            baseName + '/' + archiveName,
            baseName + '/' + baseName + '.service',
            baseName + '/Makefile',
            baseName + '/Makefile.properties' ]
    def serviceLogPath = '/var/log/' + baseName
    def commonFlags = [
            "-DsleepMicros=" + "10000"
    ]
    doLast {
        copy {
            from outputs.files.asPath
            into '../build/' + baseName
        }
        copy {
            from '../deployment/template.service'
            into '../build/' + baseName
            expand(
                    "JAR_NAME": archiveName,
                    "SPECIAL_FLAGS": specialFlags.join(" "),
                    "COMMON_FLAGS": commonFlags.join(" "),
                    "SERVICE_NAME": baseName,
                    "MAIN_CLASS": mainClass
            )
            rename('template.service', baseName + '.service')
        }
    }
}
```

I have a whole bunch of such tasks for different XXX, so i decided to create a custom task class which would help to remove duplicate code. The class looks like this:

```
class FatJarAndServicePackage extends Jar {
    String baseName
    String mainClass
    private String heapSize = '1g'
    List<String> specialFlags = []
    String serviceLogPath = '/var/log/' + baseName
    List<String> commonFlags = [
            "-DsleepMicros=" + 10000
    ]

    void setHeapSize(final String size) {
        heapSize = size
    }

    @Override
    Task doLast(final Action<? super Task> action) {
        from {
            project.configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : project.zipTree(it) }
        }
        with jar
        project.copy {
            from outputs.files.asPath
            into project.projectDir.toPath().resolve("build").resolve(baseName)
        }
        project.copy {
            from '../deployment/template.service'
            into '../build/' + baseName
            expand(
                    "JAR_NAME": archiveName,
                    "SPECIAL_FLAGS": specialFlags.join(" ") + " -Xmx" + heapSize,
                    "COMMON_FLAGS": commonFlags.join(" "),
                    "SERVICE_NAME": baseName,
                    "MAIN_CLASS": mainClass
            )
            rename('template.service', baseName + '.service')
        }
        project.copy {
            from '../deployment/Makefile.properties'
            into '../build/' + baseName
            expand(
                    "JAR_NAME": archiveName,
                    "BASE_NAME": baseName
            )
        }
        project.copy {
            from '../deployment/Makefile'
            into '../build/' + baseName
        }
        makeTar()
        return super.doLast(action)
    }
```

So it doesn't work. The thing is that i don't understand where to put the lines:

```
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
```

How should i implement these two lines in a custom task class? Appreciate any help.